# Parsing a string of space-delimited-values to struct layout

Tags: c#

For our testing projects (Specflow/C#) we have a few tests that need to parse a `string` of values (for example `1000 500 234 390`) to a structure with a fixed layout. This `string` is also of a fixed layout.

At this moment the current implementation looks as follows:

```cs
StructObject ConstructFromString(string value)
{
    var values = value.split(' ').Select(v => Convert.ToUInt16(v)).ToArray();
    return new StructObject{
        member1 = values[0],
        member2 = values[1],
        member3 = values[2],
        member4 = values[3]
    };
}
```

I was wondering if there exists some way, provided by the language, to do this kind of parsing? Or is the current implementation the best way possible?

Comment: This is not a conversion, this is parsing. Even the *characters* have no meaning by themselves until you call `uint.Parse`. [Convert.ToUInt16(string)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1000) just calls `UInt16.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);`. In fact, each Unicode character can be treated as a UInt16 itself.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, rephrased form converting to parsing.

Comment: It's not a matter of rephrasing. Converting isn't parsing and the string has no relation to the struct's layout at all. This is a custom string format that needs custom code to parse and extract its parts.

Comment: If you had multiple lines in this string we could use an CSV like approch, mapping StructObject member3  to indexes. It could be better for multiple line, with the need to handle error missing data and convert back

Comment: It can run *faster* without allocating temporary strings, if you use C# 7+ and `AsSpan()` to get a `ReadOnlySpan<char>` from the string. Otherwise, `split` generates 3 new temporary strings from the original that need to be GCd

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos sadly we can't, I think we are stuck on #5 or even 4. Guess the current implementation is good enough. I think I was just looking for some syntactic sugar, a bit like what you can do with tuples but then for class/struct members.

Comment: This is a string, not tuples. Its elements need parsing themselves. Even if you mapped a struct directly to the string's memory location, the fields would contain chars, not integers

Answer (score 1):

Few remarks:

Conversion might throw an exception, so if you don't want that, you can use `UInt16.TryParse` method:

```
var values = value.split(' ').Select(v => UInt16.TryParse(v, out short res) ? res : 0).ToArray();
```

note that `0` will be "error" value.

You can improve code little bit by defining a constructor accepting four parameters or array of ints as parameter and then call it like:

```
return new StructObject(values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3]);
```

or

```
return new StructObject(values);
```

And in constructor you will assign values.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement static method in **StructObject** with name, let's say, "**ConvertFromString**" and place all logic of converting into it.
In this case your code will look like:

```
StructObject structObject = StructObject.ConvertFromString(str);
```

Or another variant, you can use extension method. In this case your code will look like:

```
StructObject structObject = str.ConvertToStructObject();
```

Comment: Yeah, not really what I was looking for. That is just moving the code to somewhere else :-) Thanks for the effort though. I think I was just looking for some syntactic sugar, a bit like what you can do with tuples but then for class/struct members.